# Why must I use the ~ operator when clearing a bit?

Tags: c, bit

For example, if I want to set a bit in y at position n (in C)

```
y = y | (1 << n)
```

But if I want to delete a bit in y at position n I have to use the ~ operator after binary AND.

```
y = y & ~(1 << n);
```

My question: Why Must I use the ~ operator?
Is this because the result turns into negative area?

Comment: There are no "negative" number, just bits. Take a piece of paper and a pencil and do these operations by hand. Hello De Morgan.

Comment: Because to set a bit you need to OR the value with a mask having a single bit set. To reset ("delete") a bit you must AND the value with a mask having all bits set *except* that bit. The `~` inverts the single-bit mask to do the AND.

Comment: "Why Must I set the ~ operator?" No, `~` is one way.   `y = (y |(1 << n)) ^ (1 << n);` is another.  Many ways to solve this.  Unless `1` meets the width of `y`, it is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set a bit at third place from the right :

```
Y :            01001000
1 << 2 :       00000100
Y | (1 << 2) : 01001100 The | is OR, bits are set to 1 if any is 1.
```

If you want to remove the bit :

```
1 << 2 :         00000100
~(1 << 2) :      11111011  The ~ is NOT, bits are inversed
Y :              01001100
Y & ~(1 << 2) :  01001000 The & is AND, bits are set to 1 if both are 1.
```

I suggest you read more about [Bitwise operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm)

Answer (score 1):

No, `~` has nothing to do with interpreting the number as negative: tilde `~` operator interprets the number as a pattern of bits, which it then inverts (i.e. replaces zeros with ones and ones with zeros). In fact, if you apply `~` to an unsigned value, the result would remain positive.

Recall that `1 << k` expression produces a pattern of all zeros and a single `1` at the position designated by `k`. This is a bit mask that can be used to force bit at position `k` to `1` by applying OR operation.

Now consider what happens when you apply `~` to it: all `0`s would become `1`s, and the only `1` would become zero. Hence, the result is a bit mask suitable for forcing a single bit to zero by applying AND operation.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` operator turns all of the 0's to 1's and all of the 1's to 0's.  In order to clear the bint in position n you want to and it will all ones and a zero in the nth position so shift a one to the nth position and `~` invert all the bits.

Answer (score 0):

`1 << n` for `n==3` (just an example) gives you a pattern `0000000...0001000`. `~` negates the bit
pattern to `11111111....11110111`. Using the bitwise AND operator (`&`) will
only set the required bit to 0, all other remain with the same value. It's using
the fact that for a bit `b`: `b & 1 == b`.

`~` flips all bits, it has nothing to do with negative numbers.

A graphical representation for a sequence of `k`-bits

```
pos        k-1 k-2                           0
          +---+---+-------------------+---+---+
1:        | 0 | 0 |        ···        | 0 | 1 |
          +---+---+-------------------+---+---+

pos        k-1 k-2        n   n-1           0  
          +---+---+-----+---+---+---+-----+---+
1<<n      | 0 | 0 | ··· | 1 | 0 | 0 | ··· | 0 |
          +---+---+-----+---+---+---+-----+---+


pos           k-1 k-2     n   n-1           0  
          +---+---+-----+---+---+---+-----+---+
~(1<<n)   | 1 | 1 | ··· | 0 | 1 | 1 | ··· | 1 |
          +---+---+-----+---+---+---+-----+---+
```